# How to insert a custom image into Shiny plot header?

Tags: html, r, plot, shiny

In the almost-MWE code posted at the bottom, I'm trying to pull a custom image into the plot header. In the full App the user clicks on the image in order to trigger an explanatory modal dialogue. However, I can't get the image to render in the plot header in this case. In other cases where this works for me fine, I use `renderUI()`, but in this case I'm trying to render the image inside the `renderPlot()` function. Image below explains better than these words. Is there a way to do this inside `renderPlot()`?

[image]

MWE code:

```
library(shiny)
library(survival)

### define function ###
weibSurv <- function(t, shape, scale) pweibull(t, shape=shape,scale=scale, lower.tail=F)

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput("distSelect","Select distribution:",c("Weibull","Gamma")),
  sliderInput('shape','Adjust shape:',min=0,max=3,step=0.1,value=1.5),
  plotOutput("plot")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    curve(
      weibSurv(x, shape=input$shape,scale=1/0.03), 
      from=0, to=80,
      main = 
        fluidRow(
          paste(input$distSelect), # leave paste, actual App has more objects to include here
          tags$button(
            id = "explainBtn",
            class = "btn action-button",
            tags$img(src = "https://images.plot.ly/language-icons/api-home/python-logo.png")
          )
        ) 
    )
  })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Please check your example:`could not find function "weibSurv"`

Comment: Oh, sorry about that. I amended the post to include the required function. Is there a shortcut for clearing out R memory items for testing code to avoid this kind of mistake? Instead of closing/restarting R every time?

Comment: You can do `rm(list = ls())`. Should be used carefully.

Comment: Is it safer to just close/restart R as I've been doing?

Comment: No - but people tend to put it above every script they write - If it is overlooked by someone else their data might get lost.

Comment: So what's the reason for putting those tags in `renderPlot`? Why don't you separate the image from the plot?

Comment: I could separate the image from the plot, but the only way I know how to do that is using `renderUI` which you have warned me to not overuse. So basically, I want the title of the plot to show with reactive custom image to the right of the plot title; user clicks the image and explanation pops up in modal. I know how to do this with `renderUI()` but maybe there's a more direct way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use shiny's `actionLink` in this scenario:

```
library(shiny)
library(survival)

### define function ###
weibSurv <- function(t, shape, scale) pweibull(t, shape=shape,scale=scale, lower.tail=F)

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput("distSelect","Select distribution:",c("Weibull","Gamma")),
  sliderInput('shape','Adjust shape:',min=0,max=3,step=0.1,value=1.5),
  column(12, align="center",
         actionLink(inputId = "explainBtn", label = strong("Weibull"), icon = NULL, br(), img(src = "https://images.plot.ly/language-icons/api-home/python-logo.png"))
  ),
  plotOutput("plot")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    par(mar=c(5,4,0,2)+0.1) # reduce space above Plot
    curve(
      weibSurv(x, shape=input$shape,scale=1/0.03), 
      from=0, to=80,
    )
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$explainBtn, {
    showModal(modalDialog("do something useful"))
  })
  
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Interesting, first time I've seen `actionLink()`. A very clean solution.

Comment: It just creates an a-tag - but provides us with an `input`.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who favors `renderUI`, here's a solution though I would defer to ismirsehregal's `actionLink()` solution above as it is cleaner.

```
library(shiny)
library(survival)

### define functions used in App
weibSurv <- function(t, shape, scale) pweibull(t, shape=shape,scale=scale, lower.tail=F)

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput("distSelect","Select distribution:",c("Weibull","Gamma")),
  sliderInput('shape','Adjust shape:',min=0,max=3,step=0.1,value=1.5),
  uiOutput("plotHeader"),
  fluidRow(plotOutput("plot"))
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    curve(
      weibSurv(x, shape=input$shape,scale=1/0.03), 
      from=0, 
      to=80
    )
  })
  
  output$plotHeader <- renderUI({
    fluidRow(
      align = 'center',
      paste(input$distSelect), 
      tags$button(
        id = "explainBtn",
        class = "btn action-button",
        tags$img(src = "https://images.plot.ly/language-icons/api-home/python-logo.png")
      )
    )
  })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```